# Select 3 rows in SQL missing keyword

Tags: sql, oracle

```
SELECT agents.aname,products.pname,customers.cname
FROM products INNER JOIN 
(customers INNER JOIN agents 
(INNER JOIN orders ON orders.pid=products.pid) 
ON orders.cid=customers.cid)
ON orders.aid=agents.aid;
```

I am getting an error in line 4 for a missing keyword. Any ideas?

Comment: Which `DBMS` you are using

Comment: Oracle express. SQL command line currently

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the `ON` condition after each table `JOIN`

```
SELECT agents.aname, 
       products.pname, 
       customers.cname 
FROM   products 
       INNER JOIN orders 
               ON orders.pid = products.pid 
       INNER JOIN customers 
               ON orders.cid = customers.cid 
       INNER JOIN agents 
               ON orders.aid = agents.aid;
```